# How usable is BlenderCAD project right now?

Tags: software-recommendation, blender, cad

There is not much documentation in the project page. Did anyone try it on Ubuntu?

In any case, what to expect from it? Can it become a FOSS alternative to Catia, Autodesk Inventor or SolidWorks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BlenderCAD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/blendercad/) is just 7.6 kilobytes right now, which is not very promising. I couldn't compile it, but maybe I did something wrong.

There is also another (stalled) [BlenderCAD project](http://projects.blender.org/projects/blendercad/), but downloads are not working (it gives just 0 bytes files to me, tried with multiple browsers and `wget`).

Everything is possible, but that hardly will be reasonable alternative for SolidWorks (or similar). Building almost completely different (CAD) software on top of Blender (3D rendering tool) is something like converting oil truck to bus without making too many changes (both are for transportation, just for different things). It works, but it's not as good as building bus to transport humans.

Sometimes magic happens (we have working operating system, which is open source; Blender is rather huge package by itself), but SolidWorks/Autodesk Inventor/... are product of long engineering work, which can't be replicated in short timeframe (so expect waiting multiple years).

Answer (score 2):

Also see: http://www.cad4arch.com/cadtools/index.htm